# How to compile java classes independently

Tags: java, javac

I'm currently wondering if you can compile Java class files without their dependencies, like .o files in C or C++. For example, I have a class A that has an instance of class B inside, but I only want to compile class A. Is there a way to do it? The point is to compile a java program using make because Gradle and Maven just won't let me do what I want to do.

Thank you.

Comment: It's a fair question. But it may be worth exploring Gradle or Maven in a little more detail. Those two are specifically designed for Java and will do a lot of the dependency management sort of things you have to do by hand in `make` for C++.

Comment: In C or C++, we have the concept of header files, which, for all intends and purposes, are what Java calls interfaces. We can, of course, compile programs with their interfaces without compiling the implementation fo the interfaces.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I tried, and I know I probably can do it but I have a technical test for a job due tomorrow and it would be a shame to fail just because I couldn't build it. Also I probably would learn a lot about how java compilation works exactly. I already did most of the "doing it by hand" work.

Comment: No. You need the dependencies on your compiler classpath. You can compile A without compiling B, but you still need B on the classpath when you're compiling A, so the compiler can check that A is using B in a way that B allows. Here's an example of a (very simple) [Java project built with make](https://github.com/yegor256/j5inno/blob/master/Makefile). I happened to stumble across it yesterday.

Comment: You can compile a class on it's own. If it had dependencies, they need to have been compiled and available on your classpath, or if their source is found they will be compiled. So if A depends on class B then B.class needs to be on the class path. What feature do you want from make that you are not getting from maven/gradel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is a statically typed language, like C/C++, so any class or method used by your class must be well-known, in order to compile your class.

In C/C++, we use header files to define classes and methods, without implementing them. That way we can compile classes that use them, using only the headers files, not the source files of the required classes/methods.

Java doesn't have header files, so the classes/methods must be available in full. They don't have to be available as source code, i.e. they can be pre-compiled and made available as `.class` files, most often packaged in `.jar` files.

So if you have class A depending on class B, you can compile B separately, then compile A separately, as long as `B.class` is on the classpath.

Unlike C/C++, the Java compiler can compile many files together, which is e.g. needed if A and B depends on each other (circular dependency).

If A and B are part of the same project, then compile them together. If A and B are part of different projects, build project B first, resulting in a `B.jar` file, then build project A, and give the jar file on the classpath when building project A.

Comment: It might be interesting to note that you can for example offer a facade of the code, via an _interface_ or similar and then load the actual implementation at runtime.

Comment: Javac -d ./ A.java B.java

Comment: @NomadMaker As I already said: "If A and B are part of the same project, then compile them together", so I'm confused as to what your point is with that comment.

Comment: @Zabuzard When the answer says "class", read "type", as in `class`, `interface`, `enum`, and `record`. An interface is not the same as a C/C++ header file, so please don't compare the two.

Comment: @Andreas Because you didn't give an example command line. The OP sounded confused, and I wanted to make it as obvious as possible for him. I'm sorry if this bothered you.

Comment: @NomadMaker If A depends on B, then `javac A.class` will compile both too. The compiler automatically pulls in extra source files as needed, as long as it can find them, which is why there are naming restrictions on Java source files (must be named same as `public` class). This answer is about whether and/or how B has to be available when compiling A, not about the actual mechanics of doing it, which preferably should be a build tool, not `javac`.